# How to do a fisher's exact test for 5x2 table with 0 values?

Tags: spss, fishers-exact-test

I want to do a 5x2 contingency table Fisher's exact test, but I have some zero values.
How do I do this? What is the simplest way to do it?

I have access to SPSS but I know very little about the software and very little about statistics

Comment: The procedure does not vary--the presence of zero values doesn't affect it.

Comment: @Whuber What if the zeros are structural?

Comment: @Demetri That ought to show up in the results.  It's possible the software one uses might choke on such things but I see nothing in principle to prevent the test from working even when, say, an entire row or column is zero.  Try in `R`.  *E.g.*, `fisher.test(matrix(c(10,15,0, 5,20,0), 3))`.

Answer (score 1):

I confess I have no idea how Fisher's exact test for a $2 \times 5$
table is done in SPSS--or even whether it is available in SPSS. The original version of this test, for a $2 \times 2$ table and using the
hypergeometric distribution, is easy enough to do by hand, provided
the counts are small.

However, here is Fisher's exact test for a table such as you describe
done using R statistical software:

```
TBL = rbind(c(10, 5, 20, 0, 10), c(21, 9, 20, 5, 20))
TBL
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   10    5   20    0   10
[2,]   21    9   20    5   20

fisher.test(TBL)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TBL
p-value = 0.1958
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

Comment: The tables are ordered by their probability, as with a 2x2 test. See Freeman, G. H., and J. H. Halton. “Note on an Exact Treatment of Contingency, Goodness of Fit and Other Problems of Significance.” Biometrika, vol. 38, no. 1/2, 1951, pp. 141–149.  $\:$ It is available in SPSS; see https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/fisher-exact-test-rxc-table-fisher-freeman-halton-test